# Version Compatibility in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, version, fragment-shader

I am working on a project in GLSL (of which I have no experience in). I am currently not coding anything myself, just trying to run someone else's code. Unfortunately, they wrote their code using version 120, and I am trying to run it with version 330. Note: I am running this on a Mac with version 10.15. Here is the code:

```
# version 330 core
in vec3 mynormal; 
in vec4 myvertex; 

uniform mat4 modelview;

out vec4 fragColor;

uniform vec3 color;

const int numLights = 10; 
uniform bool enablelighting; // are we lighting at all (global).
uniform vec4 lightposn[numLights]; // positions of lights 
uniform vec4 lightcolor[numLights]; // colors of lights
uniform int numused;               // number of lights used  

uniform vec4 ambient; 
uniform vec4 diffuse; 
uniform vec4 specular; 
uniform vec4 emission; 
uniform float shininess; 

vec4 ComputeLight (const in vec3 direction, const in vec4 lightcolor, const in vec3 normal, const in vec3 halfvec, const in vec4 mydiffuse, const in vec4 myspecular, const in float myshininess) {

    float nDotL = max(dot(normal, direction), 0.0);
    vec4 diffuse = mydiffuse * lightcolor * nDotL;

    float nDotH = max(dot(normal, halfvec), 0.0);
    vec4 specular = myspecular * lightcolor * pow(nDotH, myshininess);

    return diffuse + specular;
}

void main (void)
{
    if (enablelighting) {
        const vec3 eyepos = vec3(0,0,0) ;
        vec4 _mypos = gl_ModelViewMatrix * myvertex ;
        vec3 mypos = _mypos.xyz / _mypos.w;
        vec3 eyedir = normalize(eyepos - mypos);

        vec3 _normal = (gl_ModelViewMatrixInverseTranspose*vec4(mynormal,0.0)).xyz ;
        vec3 normal = normalize(_normal);

        gl_FragColor = ambient;
        for (int i = 0; i < numused; ++i) {
            vec3 light_direction;
            if (lightposn[i].w == 0) {
                light_direction = lightposn[i].xyz;
            } else {
                vec3 light_position = lightposn[i].xyz / lightposn[i].w ;
                light_direction = normalize(light_position - mypos); // no attenuation
            }
            vec3 half = normalize (light_direction + eyedir);
            vec4 col = ComputeLight(light_direction, lightcolor[i], normal, half, diffuse, specular, shininess);
            gl_FragColor += col;
        }
    }
    else gl_FragColor = color ;
}
```

And here are the errors that I'm getting:

```
Compile Error, Log Below
ERROR: 0:60: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_ModelViewMatrix'
ERROR: 0:61: Use of undeclared identifier '_mypos'
ERROR: 0:61: Use of undeclared identifier '_mypos'
ERROR: 0:63: Use of undeclared identifier 'mypos'
ERROR: 0:64: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_NormalMatrix'
ERROR: 0:79: Use of undeclared identifier 'mypos'
ERROR: 0:90: Use of undeclared identifier 'mypos'
ERROR: 0:101: Use of undeclared identifier 'mypos'
ERROR: 0:112: Use of undeclared identifier 'mypos'
ERROR: 0:123: Use of undeclared identifier 'mypos'
ERROR: 0:134: Use of undeclared identifier 'mypos'
ERROR: 0:145: Use of undeclared identifier 'mypos'
ERROR: 0:156: Use of undeclared identifier 'mypos'
ERROR: 0:167: Use of undeclared identifier 'mypos'
ERROR: 0:178: Use of undeclared identifier 'mypos'
ERROR: 0:193: Use of undeclared identifier 'eyedirn'
ERROR: 0:196: Use of undeclared identifier 'normal'
ERROR: 0:196: Use of undeclared identifier 'halfy'
ERROR: 0:197: Use of undeclared identifier 'colApp'
ERROR: 0:206: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_FragColor'
ERROR: 0:208: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_FragColor'
```

After googling for a while, I realize that this is an issue with compatibility between versions. However, I don't know enough about GLSL to know how to fix this. I am hoping to modify this file to run instead of trying to write it myself to be compatible for version 330. 
Can anyone give me advice on how to modify this code to run for me?

Comment: You can't fix it. If you want to use the legacy OpenGL matrices, then you have to use GLSL version 1.20. If that is not possible and you have to use GLSL 3.30 then you have to rewrite the entire application.

Comment: @Rabbid76 what do you recommend as an alternative to the legacy OpenGL matrices?

Comment: Try `modelview` instead of `gl_ModelViewMatrix` and `inverse(transpose(modelview))` instead of `gl_ModelViewMatrixInverseTranspose`. Declare `out vec4 fragColor;` and use it instead of `gl_FragColor `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up to OpenGL 2.1. geometry was drawn by `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences or fixed function attributes. The vertex coordinates have been transformed by the current model view and projection matrix and no shader program was necessary.
For the use with a shader programs, the built in uniforms `gl_ModelViewMatrix`, `gl_NormalMatrix`, `gl_ModelViewMatrixInverseTranspose` etc, give access to the [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL) matrices. This uniforms are provided up to [OpenGL Shading Language 1.20](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.20.pdf) and were then removed.
In compatibility profile [OpenGL Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Context) such applications can still be run with the most recent OpenGL version, but the vertex shader can not be upgraded to a higher version.

In "modern" OpenGL you have to manage the matrix transformations by your own. Matrices are provided to the shader program by [Uniform variables](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Uniform_(GLSL)) (e.g. of type `mat4`).

It seams that your shader mix both technologies. I think so, because of the specification of

> ```c
> uniform mat4 modelview;
> ```

Furthermore, the fragment shader output `gl_FragColor` is deprecated. For the fragment shader output an output variable has to be declared. Your shader has such an output variable, too:

> ```c
> out vec4 fragColor;
> ```

To make your shader compile, you have to

- substitute `gl_ModelViewMatrix` by `modelview`
- `gl_ModelViewMatrixInverseTranspose` by `inverse(transpose(modelview))`
- and `gl_FragColor` by `fragColor`

`gl_NormalMatrix` is a 3x3 matrix (`mat3`) and is the upper left 3x3 of `gl_ModelViewMatrixInverseTranspose`.
`gl_NormalMatrix` can be substituted by `mat3(inverse(transpose(modelview)))`

Answer (score 1):

You don't "run GLSL" in a vacuum, absent any context beyond running a shader. A shader doesn't work outside of the context of the environment for which it was designed.

The shader you're using was written against, for example, fixed-function matrices. Those matrices don't exist in GLSL 3.30. But a program written against OpenGL 3.3 also doesn't *provide* those matrices. It is doing rendering using its own user-defined data.

If you're porting a shader to a different environment, then you either are in control of that environment or you have been told how that environment works. Either way, you know where that environment expects to have its shader data. If you don't know that, then this isn't going to work.

So all you need now is to understand what the 1.20 stuff is doing. Then you can replace references to them with your current shader environment's data (or augment it with said data if it is not already provided). Therefore:

- `gl_ModelViewMatrix`: This is the model-to-camera transformation matrix.
- `gl_ModelViewMatrixInverseTranspose`: This is the inverse/transpose of the above.
- `gl_FragColor`: This is the output color to be written by this fragment. You should instead declare a `layout(location = 0) out vec4 someName;` variable and write to that variable.
- `gl_NormalMatrix`: This is a 3x3 matrix intended to be used to transform normals. The OpenGL way of computing it is by computing the inverse/transpose of the model-view matrix.

So just substitute your data in those locations and you ought to be fine.